# symfony2 locale and validation messages

Tags: symfony, doctrine

`locale: pl` in my `parameters.yml` but my validation messages are in english not polish,
I have also try `locale: pl_PL` but this also didn't work
Each time I cleared cache

Comment: Where are your translations files (full path with the name of the files)? Is it working somewhere in your code/twig template or absolutely nowhere?

Comment: Ok. But does the translation file is load on locale variable ?? `/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Resources/translations` Im using default translations files

Comment: What do you mean by local variable? Your translation files end with `pl.extension` right?

Comment: `validators.pl.xlf`. I mean if U set locale on en U got english messages, if de U got deutchland messages, and pl to get polish messages

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works! Can you show us on sample of code where you translate some text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to uncommented the translator service of the framework component in config.yml to activate translations, also for other symfony components. Changing the paramater in parameters.yml isn't enough.

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
```

Take a look at the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html).

Comment: Thanks this is exacly what I needed